# How to create a user authentication using rails as backend and ember as frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm working on eCommerce for my internship project. But I don't know how to create the user authentication using rails and ember

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I assume the following things:

1. You are using ember to develop your frontend and will consume APIs from the backend.
2. You are using rails to create the necessary API.

If you want to authenticate users before using your API, check out the doorkeeper and devise gem. Devise takes care of things like storing your user details in the database, resetting the password, etc. The Doorkeeper gem is used to provide authentication and authorization to APIs.

Doorkeeper Link: https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper

Devise Link: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise

Comment: Thank you very much those articles were really useful.